# Bottom menu with ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, menuitem, submenu

Im trying implement the bottom menu with ActionBarSherlock. In Android 2.1, the menu are displayed, but in the Android 4, the menu is not displayed. What's wrong?

[image]

Below, the code:

```
public class Atividade extends Activity implements OnCreateOptionsMenuListener {

     ActionBarSherlock mSherlock = ActionBarSherlock.wrap(this);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11)
            // Remove title bar
            this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light_DarkActionBar);

        mSherlock.setUiOptions(ActivityInfo.UIOPTION_SPLIT_ACTION_BAR_WHEN_NARROW);        
        mSherlock.setContentView(R.layout.atividade);
        .
        .
        .               
    }
```

Below, the menu options:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        menu.add("Agenda")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_compose)
            // .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

        menu.add("Favoritos")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.favoritos)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

        menu.add("Mapa")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.maps)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

        com.actionbarsherlock.view.SubMenu subMenu1 = menu.addSubMenu("Compartilhar");              
        subMenu1.add("Facebook");
        subMenu1.add("Twitter");
        subMenu1.add("E-Mail");
        subMenu1.add("SMS");

        MenuItem subMenu1Item = (MenuItem) subMenu1.getItem();
        subMenu1Item.setIcon(R.drawable.compartilhar);
        subMenu1Item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you doing all that crap yourself instead of using a `SherlockActivity` and the manifest flag?

Comment: `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` in your `<activity>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your Activity extend `SherlockActivity`. As Jake Wharton suggests, use the manifest to set the `theme` and `uiOptions` attributes on your activity.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) (Also has demo source code) which is internally using ActionBarSherlock.
And for starters you can translate(Right click -> Translate on chrome) and use [this](http://menzerath.eu/artikel/android/actionbarsherlock-holoeverywhere/) tutorial.
Individual samples can be found [here](http://actionbarsherlock.com/download.html).